# OpenMP: Growing a shared array

Tags: fortran, openmp

I need some help on the following problem:

the result of my computations is stored in an array which is shared among the OMP threads.
Since I do not know how many entries my final result will have, I need to dynamically extend, i.e. deallocate/reallocate it, which can only happen sequentially. 
I would like to avoid checking the size every time using an OMP critical, since this slows down the code a lot and only when sufficient results are available the result array needs to be extended again.

Hence I came up with the following code, which however I do not really like (but it gets the job done):

```
if (resCnt> curAlloc) then 
    !$OMP CRITICAL
    if (resCnt> curAlloc) then 
        allocate(results_temp(1:resCnt+allocationStep))
        results_temp(1:resCnt) = results
        call MOVE_ALLOC(results_temp, results)
        curAlloc = curAlloc+allocationStep
   end if
   !$OMP END CRITICAL
end if
```

The idea behind the code above was to first check with the variable still in parallel context. 
If then one thread discovers that a "reallocation" is required, it first needs to check again, however in a critical context. Once one thread finished the critical region, the others would then notice that the condition for growing is not needed anymore and exit the critical area as well.

Is there an error in my thinking above, or better: is there a leaner way to handle growing the array? 
If it is of interest: the type of the array is a custom type and I can get results between say 1.000 and 10.000.000 (in future this upper bound may not hold anymore).

Any advice is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: you could try experimenting with [locks](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpse31.html#openmpsu157.html)? This gives you a bit more flexibility when thread can access array (prevent thread array access when it is being reallocated).

Comment: It depends on the exact structure of what you are doing, but I'd worry the above might suffer from a race condition. What happens if resCnt is incremented just after the first test is done - can the first thread write to results_temp with an illegal index before another thread has completed the Critical? Maybe there is some extra synchronisation elsewhere that stops this happening.

Comment: Is it better for each thread to write to its own private array, and then merge them at the end?

Comment: Are you sure that you do not know the size of the array? The best solution would be to figure out how large the array is going to be. This may or may not be possible, but there may be a way. Perhaps, you can loop through the array first without doing any calculations, merely for the purpose of figuring out how many elements you will end up with. This should be a cheap operation and could be cheaper than reallocating on the fly.

Comment: I am afraid the size is absolutely not known (the problem is about finding conjunctions of objects in space and there is no way of saying how many there will be, especially since the catalogs may grow in the future). I tested the above code on two high performance VMs with the same setup, except for the windows update state. On one machine it works perfectly, on the other it stops forever at for__ acquire semaphore threaded, as a VTune profiling shows. Interesting though that a race condition happens on one machine, but not on the other with the same binary and openmp library...

Comment: Race conditions are inherently unpredictable and unrepeatable

Comment: As the scope of my problem just changes, I now need to be able to quickly search the result. Hence I guess that a custom implementation of a hash is probably the better option. In this case I will then have to go for the single omp critical. Nevertheless I am curious about the "proper" way to extend a shared, allocatable structure as swiftly as possible. I guess with locks I could further narrow down the actual critical part? Cause the extension is not suitable for any atomic omp construct.

Comment: One thing I forgot: In the original implementation the outer check was performed using a private copy of resCnt and the inner using the shared variable. The private copy was obtained as part of the increment with 1 using an omp capture structure. Also the inner dependency on rescnt could be resolved by simply using size() again?

Comment: It is not clear to me what is stopping you from creating thread private arrays and merging them in the end, that seems like the most reasonable approach.

Comment: @Qubit Yes, that seems to be the most reasonable approach.

Comment: Also the thread-private arrays need to have a fixed size. Since the overall size is not known, this essentially boils down to assuming an upper size for the overall size. Also there is no guarantee for the threads to have an equal amount of results (one thread may have 10 times the results of the other), hence this is just a milder form of assuming an overall size. I am more interested in a generic solution which has no assumption on the final size, i.e. works with growing the shared array.